# How to limit max concurrency for SQS queue receivers based on each type of message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-msk

I lambda function that returns a bunch of requests that I want to send to an external service. This external service has an api with the following rate limit:

```
Paramters: 
type: enum
content: list of n elements

Rate limit: 
For each type, there can be no more than 3 concurrent slots. Each slot will be will need to wait n milliseconds between requests.
```

I want to throttle the requests being sent. My deign is to use sqs to queue the request payloads and set an autoscaling lambda to consume them. The sqs configuration includes a max_concurrency, but I dont see a way to configure that based on the message content.

Is there a way to implement the rate limit throttling described above using SQS? Or should I use another solution like Amazon MSK?

Example:

For below queue, I want a lambda function to be able to concurrently process 3 messages for type 1, 3 messages for type 2, and so on.

```
queue: 
type=1, payload
type=1, payload
type=1, payload
type=1, payload
type=2, payload
type=2, payload
type=2, payload
type=3, payload
```

Comment: What do you mean by "configure that based on the message content"?

Comment: I mean a way to configure the max concurrency based on the type of message. I want to set the concurrency of each type of message to be 3. I thought my example makes it clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of message"? It is assumed that all messages sent to an Amazon SQS queue are 'equal'. It is **not possible to selectively retrieve messages from an SQS queue** based on the content of a message or the metadata associated with a message. If you want to handle each 'type' of message differently, you would need to **create separate queues** for each message type.

Comment: Im not talking about selectivly retreiving. I mean when we do retreive a message, check the value of its "type" attribute. Type is a parameter that is in the message content. If there are more than 3 functions with that same type currently running, wait until a slot opens up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process messages differently, you would need to:

- Send the messages to an **Amazon SNS Topic**
- Subscribe **multiple AWS Lambda functions** to the SNS Topic
- Add [Amazon SNS subscription filter policies - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) to the subscriptions such that each subscribed Lambda function only receives one 'type' of message
  *OR*
- Use [Lambda event filtering - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) to filter the messages in the Lambda function's event source definition

Comment: um..... ever heard of event filtering? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html

Comment: Okay, with [Lambda Event Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html), it looks like you would still need a separate AWS Lambda function for each type, and you will still need an SNS Topic to distribute 'all' messages to every Lambda function. The Event Filter would then determine whether the Lambda function should actually process the message. So, it moves the filtering from an SNS filter to a Lambda event filters. @user23499875 feel free to add your own Answer, since you seem to be more familiar with this than me.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

- Configure the AWS Lambda function to have **Reserved Concurrency = 3**
- Add a `sleep` command to the end of your Lambda function to wait the required time

The [Reserved Concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) will ensure that a maximum of 3 functions can run at the same time.

The `sleep` will delay the start of the next function. Unfortunately, it means that the Lambda function will be running for a longer time and you will be **paying for the Lambda function to effectively do nothing**.

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want maximum 3 functions for each type. How can I do this? Type is based on the type value in the message.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could build a `eventbridge pipe` where you pass the SQS records into a `stepfunction` that redirects each type to a lambda task. The task always uses the same lambda. When you build a `map task` around it (if you have batches of the same type) you can process more by type in parallel. Its kinda overkill for the example but maybe you need to reconsider your use case and why you need that strict isolated parallelism. It feels what you need is more or less something stateful and with lambda this does not work so well with you parallelism requirements.

Note: use a express stepfunction otherwise it might be expensive.